# Watson Conversation - Getting Dialog Context to Application

Tags: watson

I've connected my chatbot (Watson Conversation) to messenger. However,
I'm stuck on passing of context variable for my Google Map API.

Process Flow:

1. **User**: I want to compute the distance
2. **Bot**: Gets `$var1` and `$var2`
3. **User**: Inputs `$var1` and `$var2`
4. **Bot**: Provides the distance between `$var1` and `$var2`

How will I be able to get the user's `$var1` and `$var2` on my Application Code?

Note: It is on Dialogue Node [2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For java just simply use :

```
    Conversation service = new Conversation("2017-07-13");
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("", "");
    MessageOptions newMessage = new MessageOptions.Builder().workspaceId("")
            .input(new 
    InputData.Builder(input).build()).context(context).build();
    MessageResponse response = service.message(newMessage).execute();
    int var1 = response.getContext().get("$var1");
```

Similarly for 2nd variable.

Comment: Thanks was able to get it now :)